# Are questions related to game recommendations off-topic in this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

Games are softwares - for as far as I know - but I am not sure, are questions related to it appropriate in this site.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the people might have different opinions on this question but my opinion is **NO** as you have mentioned in your question already simply

> **Video games are also software's** so its not off-topic as long as you are really specific about your requirement and we all will recommend whats best for you :)!